# CSV: How to write commas

Tags: punctuation, csvsimple

I have a CSV document, similar to the one in the example code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

\usepackage[textwidth=450pt, textheight=680pt,top=3cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry} %margins

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\newcommand\mce{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}}
\newcounter{Rownumb}
\newcounter{Rownumbe}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{ifthen}


\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
option, descriptionb, description, pricel, pricer
1, {a is b, which}, f, 200, 300
0, b, g, 30, 244
1, c, {h, fdsf, dsfd}, 45, 222
1, d, j, 0, 455
FALSE, FALSE, k, 0, 344
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

Example 2:\\
 \csvreader[tabular= >{\stepcounter{Rownumb}\theRownumb}r >{\everypar{\hangindent0.7cm}}p{3cm} b{1.5cm}, filter ifthen=\equal{\csvcoli}{1}]{grade.csv}{2=\dbo, 3=\deo,4=\pricel, 5=\pricer}{ & \textbf{\dbo} \deo & \mce    \\ \mce    && \$\,  \hfill \ifthenelse{\equal{\pricel}{0}}{}{\pricel,}\pricer \\ \mce}


Example 3:\\
 \csvreader[tabular= >{\stepcounter{Rownumbe}\theRownumbe}r >{\everypar{\hangindent0.7cm}}p{3cm} b{1.5cm}, filter ifthen=\NOT\equal{\opt}{FALSE}]{grade.csv}{1=\opt, 2=\dbo, 3=\deo,4=\pricel, 5=\pricer}{ & \textbf{\dbo} \deo & \mce    \\ \mce    && \$\,  \hfill \ifthenelse{\equal{\pricel}{0}}{}{\pricel,}\pricer \\ \mce}


\end{document}
```

In my real example, I have the CSV file created with an Excel file (`{`each cell's text `}`). Wherever there are commas (I found that out), I get these String/text symbols: " (highlighted in yellow)
[image: problem highlighted in yellow]

Unfortunately, I don't get it with my sample code, I can add commas and don't get it. Which suggest that Excel must save it differently. Here is the example file:
[image: CSV example]

Is there a code which I can use inside Excel to write commas? (I can `\underline` and `\textbf{` to take effect in code) Using `;` isn't really an option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) is supposed to be an example that demonstrates your problems and, as you say, your MWE does not. The unwanted quotation marks are clearly caused by the CSV files you are using. Can you post an example of the CSV output generated by excel? I don't see how anyone can help you unless you show us what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, that is the frustrating bit. I wanted to minimise my example, so created a `filecontent` table in LaTex directly and found out that it doesn't do it. For Excel: I have the table, then go to 'Save As' and select CSV.

Comment: Can you check whether the commas produced by Excel are ASCII characters, or something else?

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: How can I check this?

Comment: For instance, with tools like [this](https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/).

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat: Thank you. I have copied several cells from my CSV file into the link and if I press the Diacritics button, nothing happens. So I assume that Excel leaves the commas as ASCII characters. Is that right? (I guess, it would have been easier to fix if it was special characters?)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use CSV-sorter described in section 5.6 of the manual. I don't have this installed so I can't check this.

Comment: Probably it does mean that. Not sure. Maybe some Windows enthusiast will see this and tell you more. I do not use Excel.

Comment: I just came across [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537371/why-does-t1-encoding-has-two-comma-characters#comment1357734_537371). I have no idea what it means, but there is a chance it is relevant here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat -- Although the two "commas" in the T1 encoding have different codes, I believe (without having checked) that the non-ascii one is entered to LaTeX only through a macro as defined (for example) by a package like `csquotes`.  The T1 encoding is a *font* encoding, and what is needed for the question here is an *input* encoding.

Comment: Instead of changing your csv file you could try "a is b, which" instead of curly brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Schrödinger's cat and @ barbara beeton.

I have found a solution:
If you use `\newcommand{\comma}{, }` in your preamble and then substitute all commas in Excel with `\comma` it works beautifully.