# Why does T1 encoding has two comma characters?

Tags: font-encodings, quoting

When I was checking the T1 font encoding table, I realized there are two distinct comma characters: One at 0x0D and another one at 0x2C. They look similar but their kerning differ as far as I see.

What's the reason that there exist two versions of commas? Does one of them used as quotes? Which one?

Comment: The comma at 0x2C is the canonical comma.  The character at 0x0D is intended as an opening quotation mark.  See the note at the bottom of the last page, after the chart, of the original layout of the T1 encoding in [this TUGboat article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb11-4/tb30ferguson.pdf).